# Alternative milk Bean curd

Tags: substitutions, beans, vegetarian, soy, tofu

Can milk from beans other than soy be curdled to make a tofu-like product? I know that black beans work, but I am wondering about kidney or pinto for example (or any other). Has anyone experimented on this, before I try to reinvent the wheel? Thanks! - Judi

Comment: I have a friend who made tofu from garbanzo beans, so there's that...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if they used milk made from the beans, like you would with soy beans, or ground up dried beans?

Answer (score 1):

A curd made from chickpea flour is known as [Burmese tofu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_tofu) or shan tofu. Most [recipes](http://www.girlcooksworld.com/2013/03/burmese-chickpea-tofu.html) call for making a slurry with chickpea flour or besan flour and seasonings, simmering it until it thickens, and then chilling it in a mold of some sort. Once it has cooled, it sets and can be cut into pieces and used much like regular tofu. Many descriptions seem to place it somewhere between tofu and polenta on taste and consistency.